# Login with JWT token from query string in React app

Tags: reactjs, jwt, token

I've been playing with JWT tokens and try to implement basic email authentication without passwords and other sensitive data. So if the user want to register/login, he just fill the email in the field and then my server sends him the link with JWT token.

The token is then appended to the URL as a parameter. Now I would like to ask, how to login this user? Should I store this token to localStorage and then redirect him to the '/profile' page or is there a better approach to this problem? Is it completely okay to store the token from query string anyway?

Answer (score 0):

As you've already thougth JWT can be stored in the local storage or in the cookies. Some people even store it in the server db but I have to say that is not the best practice.

Best side of the JWT is its reproducebility.

All you have to do is decode **x-auth-token** header on the server side.

**Step 1: Create an environmental variable on the server**
You can do it on Ubuntu by simply writing `$ export myApp_jwtPrivateKey=someComplicatePrivateKey`

**Step 2: Adding the environmental variable to the back-end application**

I don't know which language do you prefer for the backend server, for me I prefer Node.js. In Node.js you have to create a config folder. My folder structure is like below;

```
 myApp/
 |──config
      |──default.json
      |──custom-environment-variables.json
 |──middleware
 |──models
 |──routes
```

Create the two  json files under the config folder. Becareful when naming the json files in the folder. If the names are not the same it won't work. 
default.json should be like;

```
{
     "jwtPrivateKey": ""
}
```

We are just defining a private key name here with an empty value.
On the *custom-environment-variables.json* file we will define the value as below;

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": "myApp_jwtPrivateKey"
}
```

Now our application can read the secret key that is stored in our server machine. Also we don't have to write our secret to anywhere.

Now on the last two parts, we will create and decode JWT using our private key.

**Step 3: Creating JWT and sending it with headers if login was successful.**

You first check the incoming credentials were fine using bcrypt package in Node.js.

```
 const validPassword = await bc.compare(req.body.password, userObject.password);
```

If *validPassword* is true we can create an token and send it with headers;

```
res.header('x-auth-token', jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))).send(token);
```

That's it. I hope it helps